# Render custom twig file for generic page template using Timber

Tags: wordpress, templates, twig, timber

I am trying to create a custom page template in WordPress, using Timber/Twig.

I have used the following code and do not understand why it's not working.
Timber docs don't provide specific examples.

I have a file named template-form-template.php, to be used for several form pages.
I prefer to select the template in admin rather than creating a page-...twig for each page slug.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Form Template
 * Description: Use this template for custom forms.
 */

$context = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();
Timber::render( 'page-form.twig', $context );

?>
```

The template name appears as expected in WordPress admin.
However, the page-form.twig is not being called.
I have a shortcode in the page I'm testing, which appears as a raw shortcode, meaning the page content is being shown but with no twig formatting.

page-form.twig content is:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <article class="post-type-{{post.post_type}}" id="post-{{post.ID}}">
            <section class="article-content">
                <h1 class="article-h1">page.twig{{post.title}}Foooo</h1>
                <div class="article-body">
                    {{post.content}}
                </div>
            </section>
        </article>
    </div>
    <!-- /content-wrapper -->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized Timber in your functions.php?

```
$timber = new Timber\Timber();
```

Or sets the view directory to find .twig files?

```
Timber::$dirname = array( 'templates', 'views' );
```

Comment: Yes, the site is built and functioning already. I just want to add a generic template option

Comment: Does the  page-form.twig reside in the same folder as your other views? I would suggest rechecking your paths to make sure there isn't a typo somewhere.

Comment: It does, and I checked spelling. I also tried nameing the php file page-form-template.php instead of template-form-template.php with a corresponding page-form.twig, but it did not work. Either I'm missing something really obvious here or the documentation could use an example of how this should be done!

Comment: Can you try instead renaming to template-custom-form.php? The page- prefix could be messing with the tempalte heirarchy

Comment: Have you referred to the documentation here: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/custom-page-templates/

Comment: Yes, specifically the section 'Custom Page Template'
"Name it something like /wp-content/themes/my-theme/template-my-custom-page.php."

Turns out I had an error in my twig file.